# Python Incorrect Values

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on an assignment that implements while and for loops to calculate the cost of tuition each year for the next 5 years, when the initial amount is 8000 and increases 3% each year.

My program works, but I'm getting the wrong values when I actually calculate the projected tuition.

```
In
-------------------
tuition = 8000
increase = 0.03
tuition_total = 0

for year in range(0, 6):
    tuition += ((tuition * increase) * year)
    print(tuition, '\t', year)

Out
-------------------
    8000.00     0
    8240.00     1
    8734.40     2
    9520.49     3
    10662.95    4
    12262.39    5
```

According to the assignment written by my teacher, here are what the values are supposed to be:

In 1 year, the tuition will be 8240.00.

In 2 years, the tuition will be 8487.20.

In 3 years, the tuition will be 8741.82.

In 4 years, the tuition will be 9004.07.

In 5 years, the tuition will be 9274.19.

Are my operations off?  Would appreciate any suggestions for what I should change.  Thanks!

Comment: Given that you're getting the wrong values, I'd say that the premise that your code "works" is false. You're multiplying by `year` when you shouldn't be.

Comment: Drop the ``year`` from ``((tuition * increase) * year)`` and you get the correct results.

Comment: Yeah, I meant I wasn't getting any errors when I ran the program.  I removed year from the operations and I'm getting the correct values now.  Thanks!

Comment: It's just a mathematical error, in handling percentage increment.
Programmatically, it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are super close. Ask yourself, why you are multiplying `(tuition * increase)` by year?

The year that the tuition increase happens should be independent of the increase itself. Thus your for loop should be of the form:

```
for year in range(0, 6):
    tuition += (tuition * increase)
    print(tuition, '\t', year)
```

This should give you the same answers that your teacher provided as well.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and the program works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Hi there, if this was the correct answer, then please mark it as such (look under the voting arrows).